# Passing a variable amount of arguments or an Array to a Journey Builder Event definition?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder

When we define an Event for Journey Builder - we select a Data Extension to hold the data, then we can use it in a Journey for personalization of messages.

But what if we don't know the exact number of arguments?

My example involves a "confirmation email" sent to a client who has subscribed to "All" classes.

The journey is fired by API.

We need to send the subscriber the list of the names of all the classes he subscribed to in the confirmation email, but those can vary from anywhere between 2-30 classes.

Is this achieveable with only one call to Fire the Journey Event + with the data load?
If so - how?
If not, what's the best way to achieve this?

Is there a way to pass an array with the names? or maybe serialize ?

Thanks!

Comment: You should consider sending the data as XML in one of the attributes in the payload. Then utilise BuildRowsetFromXml function to extract the classes: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/buildrowsetfromxml.htm

Comment: TransformXML() using an XSL template on the DE field that contains your document can also potentially be used and is a bit more flexible. You could also encode a JSON object in one of your fields and output using GTL or plain old SSJS.

Comment: Is this the simplest approach? Wouldn't it be more simple to host it in a temporary DE in that case, using Upsert, with an ID for each inject event? Then loop with Ampscript to pull data with this ID. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postDataExtensionRowsetByKey.htm

Comment: Temp DE would require two API calls. If you embed the data structure in your event trigger API call to the journey, you will have much simpler integration pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the complexity of the information regarding classes, the easiest way to solve this, if you only want to include e.g. class name, is to use [BuildRowsetFromString](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/buildrowsetfromstring.htm) function. Assuming you pass the names into parameter *classnames* as pipe delimited values:

```
First class|Second class|Different class|A whole other class|Working class
```

You can use following approach to split the string at pipes, and iterate through each class name, printing it:

```
%%[
Var @names
Var @row
Var @name
Set @names = BuildRowsetFromString(AttributeValue('classnames'),'|')
For @i = 1 to Rowcount(@names) do
Set @row = Row(@names, @i)
Set @name = Field(@row,1)
]%%
Class name: %%=v(@name)=%%<br/>
%%[
next @i
]%%
```

If you want to support a more complex data structure, than a list of values, you can use the BuildRowsetFromXML, and pass the data as XML in your journey trigger payload, Here is an example from [ampscript.guide](https://ampscript.guide/buildrowsetfromxml/) by [Adam Spriggs](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/5202/adam-spriggs) and [Eliot Harper](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/5449/eliot-harper):

```
%%[
var @xml, @isXML, @nodes, @rowCount
set @xml = ""
set @xml = concat(@xml, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>')
set @xml = concat(@xml, '<cart>')
set @xml = concat(@xml, '  <item sku="123" url="https://limedash.com?sku=123">Square</item>')
set @xml = concat(@xml, '  <item sku="246" url="https://limedash.com?sku=246">Circle</item>')
set @xml = concat(@xml, '  <item sku="789" url="https://limedash.com?sku=789">Triangle</item>')
set @xml = concat(@xml, '</cart> ')

if indexOf(@xml,"<cart>") > 0 then

  set @nodes = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"/cart/item",0)
  set @rowCount = rowcount(@nodes)
  if @rowCount > 0 then

    for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

      var @sku
      var @name
      var @url 
      set @nodepath = concat("/cart/item[",@i,"]/")
      if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"@sku"))) > 0 then
          set @sku = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"@sku"),0),1),'Value')
      endif
      if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"@url"))) > 0 then
          set @url = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"@url"),0),1),'Value')
      endif
      if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"text()"))) > 0 then
          set @name = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"text()"),0),1),'Value')
      endif
      if not empty(@sku) and not empty(@name) and not empty(@url) then
      ]%%

       <br><a href="%%=redirectto(@url)=%%">%%=v(@name)=%% (%%=v(@sku)=%%)</a>
      %%[
      endif
    next @i
  else
   output(concat("<br>no products found"))
  endif
else
  output(concat("<br>no XML found"))
endif 
]%%
```

Comment: thanks @Lukas Lunow, this is exactly serialization! How would this work if we needed to print out more than one column? e.g. the classes' Name, Type, Start Time, Instructor. ?
Would this still be adequate as a method? The alternative we're opting towards is to have a Data Extension to hold the temporary data for the sends, and loop on it with Ampscript

Comment: @LimeWeb - I have added an example utilising XML instead of a flat list

Comment: this is AMAZING ! Definitely a complete answer to the question.
I am still to try it out.