# Passing list of objects to Journey API Event Entry Source(REST)

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder

I am trying to display list(without specified length) of objects in a email, from data that is provided by a Journey API Event Entry Source. Api calls are sent from external system and should be delivered near real-time. As far as I know endpoint "POST /interaction/v1/events" accepts only simple types, that can be inserted into DE. I assume there aren't any out of the box solutions, but maybe there is some good work around (;.
What we tried:

1. Similar to answer from this post [Passing a variable amount of arguments or an Array to a Journey Builder Event definition?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/320308/passing-a-variable-amount-of-arguments-or-an-array-to-a-journey-builder-event-de) we passed json as a string and then parsed it with SSJS. Unfortunately we would have to use the work around to exceed 4000 characters limit in text field, as objects are large, and that is worrying us. Separating the list into few text fields will also probably be a no go.
2. We tried to first populate additional data extension, for list only, with "POST /data/v1/async/dataextensions/key:/rows" and then trigger journey with remaining data. This would need 2 or even 3 api calls(for confirming operation success). Also it would need a foreign key to connect list DE rows with the journey, which we are not sure we can provide.

Comment: You'd have to be more precise about your usecase for a specific recommendation. Does your usecase even have to get the JSON in near realtime, i.e. is it necessarily a journey problem or maybe an integration question? Have you tested with a DE field w/o maxlength? As you say, there are simple workarounds to achieve that, email studio UI or API; Depending on your usecase, you could also use Content builder API and update a content block with your JSON, and parse that; If it's non sensitive data, HTTPGet it onto a JSON code resource Cloudpage and parse that, if sensitive, include authentication.

Comment: thank you @JonasLamberty, we need to trigger near real time sends by api calls from external system. We want to consider other cases as we are not sure how long the field w/o maxlength will be supported.